Can the Jordan algebra of equivariant maps on symmetric matrices generated by constants and endormorphisms map any two compatible elements
Let's $G$ be a subgroup of the orthogonal matrix group $O(n)$ acting by conjugation on $V$, the space of real symmetric matrices of size $n \times n$.
Let's endow $V$ with an (non-associative) algebra structure with the product
$
* : (x, y) \mapsto \frac{1}{2}\left(xy + yv\right)
$
where $xy$ is the standard matrix product. This type of structure seems to be known as a Jordan algebra, although I am not particularly familiar with this concept.
We define $\Phi$ as the algebra generated (with the same operations as the ones on $V$) by

the $G$-equivariant endomorphisms of $V$,
the constant maps of $V$ onto itself with values in the elements fixed by $G$ (such that they are equivariant as well).

Since $G$ is a linear group and for every $g \in G$ we have $g\cdot(x*y) = (g\cdot x)*(g \cdot y)$, the maps of $\Phi$ are also $G$-equivariant.
For $x \in V$, let's $G_x \subset G$ be the stabilizer of $x$. Clearly, for any map $\varphi \in \Phi$, we have $G_x \subset G_{\varphi(x)}$ (this is true for any $G$-equivariant map).
My question is about the converse statement:
for any $(x, y) \in V \times V$ such that $G_x \subset G_y$, can we find $\varphi  \in \Phi$ such that $\varphi(x) = y$?
This could also be rephrased as the following:
for any $x \in V$, is the sub-algebra $\Phi(x) \subset V$ equal to the elements fixed by $G_x$?
I cannot find an example for which this statement is not true.
I would appreciate any help or direction on how to tackle that problem or find a counter-example.
Maybe that the Jacobson's density theorem or Burnside's theorem on matrix algebra can help, but I haven't found a way to make it work so far.
